# OutofMemory issue when reading excel file in Appengine-Java

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using Apache POI library to read excel files in to Google App engine in Java. The excel file is about 4 MB size with around 70 k records.
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

I am getting OOM error while reading this excel file.

Is there any better way of reading Excel file in Google App Engine.

Comment: What instance are you using? Does it have to be done in GAE? Alternatively you can use compute engine to get bigger instance with a fraction of GAE cost.

Comment: Sorry it has to be done in GAE.

Comment: what instance are you using? you can try to spin bigger instance